# Django blog app with comments using class views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I' wanted to try Django framework and i tried the blog app tutorial. i tried to add a comment feature. i know these questions have been asked several times but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I got the following error:
`No Post matches the given query`.

Thanks for your help. Here are the Model and all:

urls.py :

```
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('user/<str:username>/', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', PostCommentView.as_view(), name='post-comment'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
]
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # many to one relation use foreign key

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def get_comments(self):
        return self.comment_content.all()

    # return the url as string
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comment_content', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('comment-create', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

forms.py:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content=forms.Textarea()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields=['content']
```

views.py:

```
class PostCommentView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['content']
    template_name = 'blog/comment_form.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs.get('id'))
        print(post.id)
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = post
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

comment_form.htlm:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_filters %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Comment tag</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post comment</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Abort the Comment? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Back to Main Page</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Try to move this line ` path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', PostCommentView.as_view(), name='post-comment'),` above all other paths. It may just be due to wrong url endpoints being triggered inadvertently

Comment: Could you show the complete error that appeared to you

Comment: it's a 404 error saying : No Post matches the given query.
i guess error is comming from the form_valid method where i try to get the Post object using :  post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs.get('id'))

Answer (score 0):

'id' is standard primary key of a Django Model but not of the POST that is created with ModelForm etc.
I suppose you need to put a hidden field "id" in your form to get it sent with the POST request.
Try print(self.kwargs.get('id')) before the 'get_object...' and you will see if 'id' has some content.